# Error in constructs, argument is missing, with no default (R)

Tags: r, modeling, equation, structural-equation-model

I have the following measurement model (SEM) but when I try to run it I keep getting the following error:

> Error in constructs(composite("l2", multi_items("x", 21:24), weights =
> mode_A),  :    argument is missing, with no default

What can I do to solve it? Any ideas ?
Thank you all in advance!!
Best,
Andrea

```
library(seminr)
# Create measurement model  
mm_lock <- constructs(
  composite("l2", multi_items("x", 21:24), weights = mode_A),
  composite("l3", multi_items("x", 29:32), weights = mode_A),    
  composite("l4", multi_items("x", 43:45), weights = mode_A),  
  composite("l5", multi_items("x", 49:52), weights = mode_A),     
  composite("l6", multi_items("x", 57:59), weights = mode_A), 
  composite("l7", multi_items("x", 63:65), weights = mode_A), 
  composite("l8", multi_items("x", 69:70), weights = mode_A), 
  composite("l9", multi_items("x", 71:74), weights = mode_A),
  composite("l10", multi_items("x", 81:83), weights = mode_A), 
  composite("l11", multi_items("x", 87:89), weights = mode_A),  
)
```

Comment: you have a comma too much after your last composite argument `composite("l11", multi_items("x", 87:89), weights = mode_A), ` <- this one

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this! It got solved :-)